# Camera picture pixels measure - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to measure object pixels using WP camera(precisely Lumia 800).

i.e. if i have shape recognized(a square, for example) is there a way to measure width and height in pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but you may be able to use the [SLARToolkit](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/) to do measure an object like you require...

Answer (score 2):

If you allready know where the shape resides and are looking for a better/faster image editing library use [Image tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/releases/view/53740). I've used them in the past to filter out everyhting but a particular shade of red thus making image recognition a lot easier